# Jquery flot piece edges broken

Tags: jquery-plugins, flot, pie-chart

I have drawn a pie chart using jquery flot pie, but its edged at the top and bottom are somewhat slightly cut

[image: here]

I didn't change anything (except data) from when I bought this [Wrap bootstrap](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0B79M8D) theme and as you can see it also has this problem in all pie charts. What could be the reason for this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this got fixed with a newer combination of plugins:

```
v0.7 to v0.8 of jquery.flot.js
```

and

```
v1.0 to v1.1 of jquery.flot.pie.js
```