# Jquery flot pie chart going crazy

Tags: jquery, label, flot, pie-chart

I have a very simple chart, no interesting code behind the scenes, but every time, the chart is loaded differently, alternating between two ways of placing the labels like this:
[image]

All the labels seem to be pushed up into different locations. I am using:

- jquery v 1.7.1 (I later updated to v 1.11, but nothing changed)
- jquery flot v 0.7 (I later updated to v 0.8, but nothing changed)
- jquery flot pie v 1.1

and the code behind this is:

```
var options = 
{
    series: {
        pie: {
            show: true,
            label: {
                show: true,
                formatter: function (label, series)
                {
                    return '<div style="font-size:8pt;text-align:center;padding:2px;color:white;background-color:#000">' + label + '<br/>' + Math.round(series.data[0][1]) + '%</div>';
                }
            }
        }
    },

    legend: {
        show: false
    }
};

$.plot($('#chart'), data, options);
```

Html of the paceholder div:

```
<div id="#chart" style="margin: 40px 20px 20px 0px; padding: 0px; 
                        position: relative; width:400px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: Can you show the html for the placeholder div?  Does it change size with the browser window?

Comment: @Mark updated as requested

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius can you prepare a fiddle for it?

Comment: Did upgrading to a newer version of Flot solve this, as it did in your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421614/jquery-flot-piece-edges-broken)?

Comment: @DNS Yes, sorry, I forgot this question at all :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this got fixed with a newer combination of plugins (just as my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421614/jquery-flot-piece-edges-broken)):

```
v0.7 to v0.8 of jquery.flot.js
```

and

```
v1.0 to v1.1 of jquery.flot.pie.js
```